# Can you patent something that was published 20 years earlier: US 8449413 B1

Tags: us8449413b1

US 8449413 B1

This patent was in a book with a copy date of 1990, describing freely to any one on how to make them, then this was filed in 2011.

Here is a link to the book: http://www.larping.net/Nero/Nero3ed.pdf

Comment: If the publication describes the construction of the arrow in sufficient details, then it could be considered a prior art and used to challenge validity of the patent. Can you specify the page which describes the arrow?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. As Daniel said, it would be useful to include some more details, so our community doesn't have to read and understand the full book. Could you please check out [How do I write a good prior art request?](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/questions/47/how-do-i-write-a-prior-art-request-for-a-u-s-patent-application/146#146), and try and include some details like that template does? Which part of the patent do you feel is covered in that book? Where in the book is it covered? Things like that would go a long way in helping get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't studied the cited patent, it is important to understand that the general area of a patent is often similar or the same as much prior art. If for instance someone publishes the idea of foam tipped arrows, another person could devise a novel and non obvious method of constructing foam tipped arrows and obtain a patent. That patent wouldn't keep others from making foam tipped arrows in general, but would keep them from using the patented construction method.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the previous answer: It may TECHNICALLY be possible to obtain such a patent, because patent offices can't check everything.

The fact that it has been found in a book means (by definition) that there is published prior art, so the patent is worthless.

If its not too late this information may be enough for an examiner to kill it. Otherwise it would end up being challenged... maybe... in court some day with the book cited as the prior art.